# No permissions to run the selected query in App Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

When I go to App Insights -> Activity Log I get:

> No permissions to run the selected query.

---

Is that because there are no queries to run?  Or is it really a permissions problem?

[image: app insights of error]

---

I have defined two queries but they don't show up in the dropdown.  Should they?

Where can I read more about this?  [The docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics) didn't help me very much.

[image: my queries screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that the user has access to the following azure provider in addition to the obvious ones.

"microsoft.insights/eventtypes/*"

you could also try "microsoft.insights/*/read", in case you want the role to view all monitoring data from Azure Monitor.

more on custom roles & RBAC is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

To configure custom roles in Azure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-powershell

Activity Log interaction is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/activitylogs_list